# How to give access and partial access to specifc Users in ORACLE database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view in an Oracle database whereby if a USER is in the PLAYER field of the base table, only the rows of this player are outputted, but if a USER matches the MANAGER role of another base table, all rows of this first base table are outputted.

So far I have this which I'm not sure even works?

```
CREATE VIEW Player_view AS
SELECT (CASE WHEN USER IN PT.PLAYER THEN (SELECT * FROM PT WHERE USER = PT.PLAYER)
ELSE WHEN USER IN PM.MANAGER THEN (SELECT * FROM PT)
END
FROM Player_Table PT, Player_Managers PM
```

Otherwise, I have tried with grant permissions - however, how do I give grant permission to SELECT over just one row vs. all rows?

Comment: "User" as in a "real" database user (can directly log in to Oracle)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like the following should suffice

```
create view player_view as
select * from player_table
where player = user
union all
select * from player_table
where exists ( select 1 from player_manager where manager = user )
```

If the two are not mutually exclusive, then you could add a 'not exists' to the second query

```
create view player_view as
select * from player_table
where player = user
union all
select * from player_table
where exists ( select 1 from player_manager where manager = user )
and player != user
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't used Union all before but this is perfect!!